# After crash, images appear as black sihoettes and all text dissappears

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, system

I had several instances of blender running, and they all crashed at once as I started a render with a procedural materials.
Now, when I load:

- All images in viewports are black silhoettes.
- Text and icons are missing from all tiles.
- Points on timeline still showm but all text on timeline titles is
  gone.

Refer attached images.

I have tried:

1. Uninstalling then installing new blender version.
2. Shutting down and restarting the computer.
3. Running disk cleanup to clear cache.
4. Clearing App data files on my profile.

None of this has made any difference.[image]

It looks like a rendering issue. But I still have larger, more demanding bits of software (such as Revit) running fine.

I'd appreciate any help.

[image: Crash_2]

[image: Crash_1]

Comment: When the interface gets corrupted like that, it is because of issues with the GPU. update or downgrade the drivers for it.

Comment: Thanks susu. I've updated my drivers but it has had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my graphics card, a GeForce GTX1070, doesn't have enough muscle :(
After 10 or so reboots this appeared:

[image]

The old card has no updates that work. Frustrating. I don't know what I'm going to do about this.

Comment: I think this card is well above the minimum requirements. You should try updating your drivers as indicated in the error message

Comment: Thanks Gorgious. I've updated my drivers but it has had no effect.

Comment: Unless your card is fried (it can happen) 1070 should be working fine with blender. upgrade or downgrade the drivers for it.